# Trying to make a knob with kinetic.js

Tags: kineticjs

I am trying to make a knob with kinetic.js 
I managed to rotate and get value out of it but I can't think 
of a logic to keep the previous position whenever new event on knob are called

Here is the example,

Here is my dragBoundFunc,

```
dragBoundFunc: function(pos) {
    knobLine.setRotationDeg( pos.x );
    return {
        x: this.getAbsolutePosition().x,
        y: this.getAbsolutePosition().y,            
    }             
}
```

I've tried

```
knobLine.setRotationDeg( knobLine.rotation() + pos.x );
```

However it seemed like its working at first but incremented values are not constant

Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's one way using trigonometry:**

- listen for clicks in the knob circle.
- calculate the angle of the click versus the knob's centerpoint.
- reset the knob line endpoint using trigonometry.

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/h1vpupkd/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.1.0.min.js"></script>
<style>
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 350,
        height: 350
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    var knob=new Kinetic.Circle({
        x:100,
        y:100,
        radius:18,
        stroke:'red',
    });
    knob.on('click',function(){
        var cx=this.x();
        var cy=this.y();
        var radius=this.radius();
        var pos=stage.getPointerPosition();
        var mouseX=parseInt(pos.x);
        var mouseY=parseInt(pos.y);
        var dx=mouseX-cx;
        var dy=mouseY-cy;
        var angle=Math.atan2(dy,dx);
        var lineX=cx+radius*Math.cos(angle);
        var lineY=cy+radius*Math.sin(angle);
        line.points([cx,cy,lineX,lineY]);
        layer.draw();
    });
    layer.add(knob);

    var line=new Kinetic.Line({
        points:[100,100,100,85],
        stroke:"red"
    });
    layer.add(line);

    layer.draw();


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Click in knob to reset line.</h4>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but I am trying to make a knob that is dragable

Answer (score 1):

Get radian value by using `Math.atan2(y,x)` and convert the radian to degree `radian/Math.PI*180`.

```
dragBoundFunc: function(pos) {
    var theta = Math.atan2(pos.y,pos.x);
    knobLine.rotation(theta/Math.PI*180+45);
    return {
        x: this.getAbsolutePosition().x,
        y: this.getAbsolutePosition().y,
    }
}
```